# How to update two tables in relationship in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Example: I have Table A and Table B they are in relationship one to many.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must input an example from your codes. Otherwise, this question will not be answered by the Seniors because of lack of information. Please improve your question formatting. Anyhow, here is the docs that might help you.
 [Sequelize Relations/Associations](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/associations/)